# Matches, mismatches and indels

Tags: sequence-alignment, indel, phred-scores

I have a bam-file of reads and reference genome. How can I located matches, mismatches and indels in three different files with Phred score in each data of the files?

Answer (score 4):

Try one of these:

GATK:
https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360036194592-Getting-started-with-GATK4

freebayes:
https://bioinformaticsworkbook.org/dataAnalysis/VariantCalling/freebayes-dnaseq-workflow.html#gsc.tab=0